# How can I remove some portion of my background base on other layer?

Tags: logo, layers, icon, layer-style, favicon

I know very little when it comes to design.

I have 2 layers - a text on top of a background.

[image]

result

[image]

How can I delete/take-off the shape of my layer 1 out of my layer 0 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select layer 1 in the Layers Panel, make sure it is highlighted.  Click on the selection tool, I would suggest the Magic Wand tool if you're using Photoshop. 
[image: Selecting layer 1 in the layers panel and clicking on the object you want to knock out]

Select/highlight the areas you wish to knock out of the layer 0. Then, with that area still highlighted, click on layer 0 in the layers panel.

[image: Select layer 0]

Press delete on your keyboard. And hide Layer 1 so only Layer 0 is visible (click on the eye next to the layer).

[image: Deleted image]

From there, you can fill in with another color using the paint bucket tool or do whatever you'd like. If you would rather have your selected graphic be the color of Layer 0, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (on a PC) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (on a Mac) to invert the selection and then click Layer 0 on the layers panel and delete.

Comment: I kind of did the same thing as you answer. Thank-you ! :)

Comment: Love the screenshot of each step.

Answer (score 4):

- Hold the <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd> key down and click the **layer thumbnail** for the "B". This will load a selection.
- Highlight the green layer
- Hold the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key down and click the `New Mask` icon ([image]) at the bottom of the **Layers Panel**.

This will provide a *non-destructive* way to remove one layer's contents from another. Working *non-destructively* has great benefits and should be done whenever possible. It allows you to alter things later since all the original image data is still there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is more than 1 solution for this, but here is how I solve this :

1. I kind of zoom in for a better selection,
2. I use **" Magic Wand Tool "** to select on my text while on my
   text layer.
3. Then, select my background layer and hit `delete` button.

Here is my result

[image]

**Note** : I change the background-color to black for you guys easier to see.

Comment: In Photoshop, when you ctrl-click a layer (well, the little image of it) you automatically select all non-transparent pixels. Just saved you three seconds :)